# Looking for a presentation about information security for corporate employees

Tags: corporate-policy, user-education

I'd appreciate if you could recommend me a presentation the describes the dangers and possible solutions and guidelines, when using the Internet. Specifically, in corporate settings. I would need to change and adapt it to our needs, so it has to have a suitable license, something like CC.

A good example of such a presentation is the one called "[Internet Safety at Work](http://www.uschamber.com/issues/technology/internet-security-essentials-business)", but it is not comprehensive enough for my needs.

Comment: I think this is one of the cases when "rolling your own" is a valid option. Look at a range of presentations and find the parts that are relevant to your company, then use them to create your own presentation. Since you're just using the existing presentations as sources, it's not a derivative work. One of the greatest things you can include is a practical demonstration, showing how easy it is for you to break into things when employees make bad security decisions.

Answer (score 3):

This is a hot issue right now and many people write high-quality education programs, so I'm not sure that you are going to find CC licensed options. Add to that the fact that every corporate environment is *different* (as you indicate), I don't feel like you are going to find something for free that meets your needs.

You ask for 'dangers, and possible solutions and guidelines'. That is WAY too broad. If you broke down what *specifically* you want your users to know and what behaviours you want to instil, you might find some options that could work. Going through the process of defining that knowledge set and response behaviours would also help you to define a way to measure the effectiveness of your training.

Answer (score 1):

There is a perfect resource for just exactly this over at SANS [Securing The Human](http://www.securingthehuman.org). They send out a monthly newsletter aimed specifically for the average internet users. The primary goal is to educate them to provide better security. The newsletter can be found here: [newsletter](http://www.securingthehuman.org/resources/newsletters/ouch). The newsletters also come translated in a wide variety of languages.

Some of the previous topics per month:

- August: Counterfeit Websites
- July: The Tech-Support Phone Call Scam
- June: Using The Cloud Safely
- May: Safely Disposing of Your Mobile Device
- April: Metadata
- March: E-mail Dos and Don'ts
- February: Securing Your Mobile Device Apps
- January: Secure your Wi-Fi Network